# "Further established in" vs. "further established by"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, collocation

Are both these usages correct, and if so, is one preferred?

> - ... and was further established **in** follow-up studies (e.g., Doe et al., 2013).
> - ... and was further established **by** follow-up studies (e.g., Doe et al., 2013).

The intent is that the follow-up studies helped to confirm/establish the original premise. I am uncertain if "in" or "by" is more appropriate. I personally think both are fine, but I am far from an expert in English and may be overlooking an important nuance.

Comment: I think you are not asking whether something is ***“grammatically** correct”*.

Comment: I removed "grammatically correct" as the phrase is incorrect. I am asking if both usages are correct, and if so, should one be preferred over the other.

Answer (score 1):

While both forms are grammatically correct, by my estimation, in an academic paper I would go with "**by**" in a sentence like that.

Unfortunately, I can't give you so much as a reason why. I can come up with various arguments why I would use that instead, but they don't sound particularly convincing even in my own mind. I guess I could just put it down to seeing that phrasing used more in academic papers (which I write fairly often and read even more often).

As a test, I gave a google search for "established by studies" and "established in studies", and added filetype:pdf - which has a greater chance of yielding complete peer reviewed papers, and is in my experience a more reliable way of getting peer reviewed stuff than Google Scholar, but I digress.

The results were close:

> established in studies filetype:pdf
>
> About 74,300,000 results (0.38 seconds)

---

> established by studies filetype:pdf
>
> About 74,600,000 results (0.37 seconds)

Comment: Good idea on the google search, although you should add quotes around that word usage or google uses an OR operator between each term (e.g., "'established by studies' filetype:pdf").  I redid your queries in scholar.google.com (without the 'filetype:pdf' filter) and found 3,480 results in favour of the "in" usage and  2,560 in favour of the "by" usage.

Comment: Crud, how could I forget the quotes >.< Redid the search too, and yep, same frequencies appear. Well damn, maybe "in" is more often used after all.